# Processes still keep running after Service Fabric App is removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-service-fabric

I have seen that when I remove a service fabric application.
The old processes for the services inside the application still keep running.

The services included in the Apps are of types

- Actors
- Stateless Services
- ASP.NET Core

I noticed the problem when I redeployed the application and the ASP.NET Core service threw an error for "EADDRINUSE address already in use"

Is there a proper way to cleanly remove the application which stops all the internal processes for the services?

Is there any cancellation event which can be captured in the processes?

I am using the following class for Registering it as a Stateless service.

```
/// <summary>
/// A specialized stateless service for hosting ASP.NET Core web apps.
/// </summary>
internal sealed class WebHostingService : StatelessService, ICommunicationListener
{
    private readonly string _endpointName;

    private IWebHost _webHost;

    public WebHostingService(StatelessServiceContext serviceContext, string endpointName)
        : base(serviceContext)
    {
        _endpointName = endpointName;
    }

    #region StatelessService

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(_ => this) };
    }

    #endregion StatelessService

    #region ICommunicationListener

    void ICommunicationListener.Abort()
    {
        _webHost?.Dispose();
    }

    Task ICommunicationListener.CloseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _webHost?.Dispose();

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var endpoint = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoint(_endpointName);

        string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}";

        _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                       .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                       .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                       .Build();

        _webHost.Start();

        return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
    }

    #endregion ICommunicationListener
}
```

And Registering it like this

```
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("WebApiType", context => new WebHostingService(context, "ServiceEndpoint")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: Yes, it's called [RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start).

Comment: did you see this article about hosting aspnet core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore    it may help if you use 'AspNetCoreCommunicationListener'

Comment: @LoekD did look into the article. Updated to use WebListenerCommunicationListener. But I still get the error **"The prefix 'http://+:8800/' is already registered."** on upgrade or remove and install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out with empty WebApi, one you get from the service fabric .NET core WebApi templates.
Continued to add features till I could see services not shutting down properly.

I found out that we were injecting controllers with Unity.

As we should not be injecting controller, I updated to remove that and also updated other Injections via Unity in favor of the built in IServiceCollection injections.

After these changes I do not see port already in use errors when I upgrade.
I do see the old process still running though but not using any CPU and memory(0.1M) and then die out after 10-15mins.

Answer (score 0):

The host process will only hang around if there is still a service replica in it. If all service replicas are removed, the host process will exit.

If you've removed the entire application and the host processes are still running, it most likely means your service code is not responding when asked to close. Either you have a RunAsync method that isn't listening to its cancellation token, or you have an ICommunicationListener that isn't closing when CloseAsync is called (maybe you have outstanding requests that are taking a while to complete).

Comment: I hadn't overridden the RunAsync as you can see in the question above.

Comment: For now I updated to use service-fabric-aspnetcore packages to initialize IWebHost and leave it's management to the package. Looking at the Git repo "AspNetCoreCommunicationListener.cs" I don't see any handling on RunAsync there too but I still see the same issues. For now as a workaround I am using random ports and using the Naming service for external communication.

Comment: I work with @villuMal. We are experiencing errors during diff upgrades related to port conflicts when using dynamic ports. We also noticed via Task Manager that the WebApi WebListener Stateless Service .exes are not shutting down in an sort of reasonable time. We are using the your examples and the AspNet Core VS2017 most recent templates. It seems RunAsync is not being called while shutting down. Unless the cluster has some sort of open communication with the services there is no outstanding requests to these services.